# Compare a list with mongodb fields in collection

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a collection `User`having document structure like,

```
{
    "_id": "ObjectId('5e8baxxxxxe400a')",
    "Email":"xxx1@gmail.com",
    "Favourites": ["Red","Blue","Green","Orange","Black"]
},
{
    "_id": "ObjectId('5e8baxxxxxe4002')",
    "Email":"xxx2@gmail.com",
    "Favourites": ["Purple","Pink","Magenta","White","Black"]
},
{
    "_id": "ObjectId('5e8baxxxxxe4002')",
    "Email":"xxx3@gmail.com",
    "Favourites": ["Red","Yellow","Grey","White","Black"]
},
{
    "_id": "ObjectId('5e8baxxxxxe4002')",
    "Email":"xxx4@gmail.com",
    "Favourites": ["Green", "White","Pink"]
},
{
    "_id": "ObjectId('5e8baxxxxxe4002')",
    "Email":"xxx5@gmail.com",
    "Favourites": ["Green", "White","Black"]
},
```

I am trying to get all the result that have `Red` or `Black` in its favourites with very low waiting time

My output should be like:

```
{
    "_id": "ObjectId('5e8baxxxxxe400a')",
    "Email":"xxx1@gmail.com",
    "Favourites": ["Red","Blue","Green","Orange","Black"]
},
{
    "_id": "ObjectId('5e8baxxxxxe4002')",
    "Email":"xxx2@gmail.com",
    "Favourites": ["Purple","Pink","Magenta","White","Black"]
},
{
    "_id": "ObjectId('5e8baxxxxxe4002')",
    "Email":"xxx3@gmail.com",
    "Favourites": ["Red","Yellow","Grey","White","Black"]
},
{
    "_id": "ObjectId('5e8baxxxxxe4002')",
    "Email":"xxx5@gmail.com",
    "Favourites": ["Green", "White","Black"]
},
```

I have tried using the query,

```
favourite = ['Red','Black']
res = db.User.find({"Favourites" : {"$in": favourite}})
```

But I got 0 results.
What should be the query to get the desired output?

Comment: Are you running these commands on the mongo shell?

Comment: Your query looks fine to me. Perhaps you are looking into the wrong db?

Comment: No, I am trying it on my jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this command.

```
db.User.find({
  "Favourites": {
    $elemMatch: {
      $in: [
        "Red",
        "Black"
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: How the Query should be like if I want the results which should have both ```Red ``` and ```Black``` ?

Comment: I have tried using ```$setEquals``` but i got ```OperationFailure: unknown operator: $setEquals```

Comment: db.User.find({"Favourites":{$all:["Red","Black"]}})

Comment: read this document https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/